# Make UIView Landscape Orientation in UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have added a UIView as subview of my UIViewController, when I am trying change the orientation, it is not working, Please let me know how should i change the Interface orientation of my UIView?

Regards

Sri

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:@selector(setOrientation:) withObject:(id)UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you return `YES` for `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `setOrientation` is a private API according to the documentation of UIDevice (that property is read only). If you use it, your application will be rejected during the App Store review.

Instead forcing an orientation, you should override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` in all the view controllers of the hierarchy of that view and return `YES` only for the orientations you want to support.